# Python 3: No module named 'sklearn.model_selection'

Tags: python, networking, import, model

I am trying to learn Neural Networks via the Keras Deep Learning Library in Python.  I am using Python 3 and referencing this link: [Tutorial Link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/)

I try to run the code below but get the following error:

ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.model_selection'

```
import numpy
import pandas

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you install wrong version of sklearn.

Please try this:

`import sklearn
print (sklearn.__version__)
0.17.1`

If your version is below 0.18, please update with `pip install -U scikit-learn` or `pip3 install -U scikit-learn`

If you have `import Error`, please install sklearn with `pip install scikit-learn` or `pip3 install scikit-learn`

Comment: thank you for the instructions.  I ended up installing the update but it still errored at here: 

ImportError: cannot import name 'rankdata'                                          ; ---> 32 from ..utils.fixes import rankdata

Comment: It's likely that you installed with conda but updated with pip. Don't do that. Uninstall scikit-learn, delete the folder, and reinstall using either conda or pip. I'd recommend conda if you are using anaconda. via @amueller on GitHub

Comment: yes, you are correct; I installed with conda.  I found that updating my numpy with 'conda install ...' automatically updated everything else too

Comment: if it didn't help? So what?)

Comment: @Oleksandr remove your scikit-learn and install newest version. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for python3

```
pip3 install -U scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 2):

This command works for me in ubuntu and Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sklearn
```

For Python 3 use this command:

```
sudo apt install python3-sklearn
```